# Google App Engine app.yaml file for PHP app (Magenta App)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, magento, yaml, google-app-engine-patch

I am working on this app.yaml file to put Magento app on GAE.  I have read most replies related to app.yaml files. Here is one for wordpress app. However, I feel very confused with so many different versions.
https://github.com/eGlobeBizCom/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/blob/9130e8ca06fa52a84821b8faffa49b83792b8ebf/app.yaml

But, the Magento app and Drupal structures are different from Wordpress app. I have tried several versions of app.yaml, not working. I really wish to find out what are the exact rules for the correct code in the  app.yaml file for PHP apps, thus newbies can test apps on GAE very quickly without this big huddle. Thank you !

Comment: Have you read this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig

Comment: Hello IanGSY: Thank you very much for this link. I have read this read before I posted my Q. My issue is: What are the really difference between the two versions of Yaml files in this link. I found out that many people made mistakes in their Yaml files in uploading their apps to Google App Engine and wasted lots of time on this. I hope to find out the Clear and Simple rules in Yaml file for using GAE for the long run.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, the app.yaml must always be present and corresponds to your default module.
You can see your modules at the google developer console -> appengine -> versions (should be modules). Each module can have lots of versions.

E.g.: To serve your application files (php files only) and your static files (everything else) from different modules, have a look at the following app.yaml and xml.yaml files:

app.yaml:

```
application: viewneo-eu
version: pro # production
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
instance_class: F4
automatic_scaling:
    min_idle_instances: 1 # one instance idleing forever
    max_idle_instances: 4 # 4 x 50 = 200 max requests
    min_pending_latency: 10ms # wait at least, before launching a new instance
    max_pending_latency: automatic # after this time, create a new instance
    max_concurrent_requests: 50

default_expiration: "0m"

handlers:
- url: /(.+)?/?
secure: always
script: build/mod_rewrite.php

- url: /.*
secure: always
script: build/mod_rewrite.php
```

xml.yaml:

```
application: viewneo-eu
module: xml
version: pro
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1 # one instance idleing forever
  max_idle_instances: 4 # 4 x 50 = 200 max requests
  min_pending_latency: 10ms # wait at least, before launching a new instance
  max_pending_latency: automatic # after this time, create a new instance
  max_concurrent_requests: 50

default_expiration: "0m"

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(appcache|manifest))
  mime_type: text/cache-manifest
  static_files: static/html/\1
  upload: static/html/(.*\.(appcache|manifest))
  expiration: "0m"
  application_readable: true
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"

- url: /(.*\.atom)
  mime_type: application/atom+xml
  static_files: static/html/\1
  upload: static/html/(.*\.atom)
  expiration: "1h"
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"

- url: /(.*\.htc)
  mime_type: text/x-component
  static_files: static/html/\1
  upload: static/html/(.*\.htc)
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"

- url: /(.*\.html)
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: static/html/\1
  upload: static/html/(.*\.html)
  expiration: "7d"
  application_readable: true
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"

- url: /(.*\.tpl)
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: static/html/\1
  upload: static/html/(.*\.tpl)
  expiration: "7d"
  application_readable: true
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"

- url: /(.*\.rss)
  mime_type: application/rss+xml
  static_files: static/html/\1
  upload: static/html/(.*\.rss)
  expiration: "1h"
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"

- url: /(.*\.txt)
  mime_type: text/plain
  static_files: static/html/\1
  upload: static/html/(.*\.txt)
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"

- url: /(.*\.xml)
  mime_type: application/xml
  static_files: static/html/\1
  upload: static/html/(.*\.xml)
  expiration: "1h"
  application_readable: true
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

I've split various content types to different modules, which requires dispatch.yaml:

dispatch.yaml:

```
application: viewneo-eu

dispatch:

- url: "fonts.viewneo-eu.appspot.com/*"
  module: fonts

- url: "img.viewneo-eu.appspot.com/*"
  module: img

- url: "css.viewneo-eu.appspot.com/*"
  module: css

- url: "js.viewneo-eu.appspot.com/*"
  module: js

- url: "html.viewneo-eu.appspot.com/*"
  module: html

- url: "cdn.viewneo-eu.appspot.com/*"
  module: cdn

- url: "video.viewneo-eu.appspot.com/*"
  module: cdn

- url: "audio.viewneo-eu.appspot.com/*"
  module: cdn

- url: "dev.viewneo-eu.appspot.com/*"
  module: dev

- url: "beta.viewneo-eu.appspot.com/*"
  module: beta
```

As we're using secure always in our app.yaml and ssl won't work for wildcard sub sub domains, you can always access these through

https://fonts-dot-viewneo-eu.appspot.com,
https://img-dot-viewneo-eu.appsport.com,
...

and so on.

Hope that helps.

Regards

Ron

Comment: Ron, Thank you so much for this detailed reply.  I will try more following your reply, and will update here if the above fix my problem.